# TImageList - True color + alpha channel vs. 8-bit (256 colors)

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, delphi-2009

I use c++ Builder 2009 but I tagged this for Delphi as well since I expect the exact same issue to exist there as well.

I use `TImageList` (16x16) and associate it to `TListView` (SmallImages) and `TTreeView`.

I was adding new icons via the IDE (design time) and imported some 16x16 True color + alpha channel icons.  In the IDE they looked fine:

[image]

During run time, they do not look fine at all:

[image]

Notice the edges especially.  The top icon is icon 5 and the bottom icon is icon 7.  See how they are supposed to look in above picture.

When I convert the icons to 8 bit (256 colors) icons and import them via the IDE, they look fine during run time !  So that is certainly a solution for me.  But the icons obviously lose information and though probably hardly noticeable in 16x16 icons, it sort of bugs me that I cannot find why this happens ?

The ImageList is created at design time and has its default properties.

I also tried: `DrawingStyle = dsTransparent` and `ColorDepth = cd32Bit` after which I had to import the icons again via the IDE.
The result is the same.  I wonder if I need to set a particular `BlendColor` ?

Do I need to do something special for it to support true color icons ?
Or is the issue with TTreeView and TListView ?
Is this a VCL limitation or Windows or .. 
Thoughts, suggestions ?

**- Additional information -** after having read David's comment.

I added a new TImageList to my project and added the 32bit icons with alpha channel.  Next I 'hacked' my code to always use that ImageList and it worked beautifully.

What I do in the code is, because I have a set of icons that I use for all OS (very application related) and because I also use icons that are OS specific, such as folder icons, CD icons etc.   I have an ImageList that contains all icons (OS and app specific) and on program start and OS check, I copy the OS icons that I need from one list to the list that I use.

Like so:

```
TIcon *Icon = new TIcon() ;
for (int x = 0 ; x < OS_Specific_count ; x++)
  {
  OS_xx_ImageList->GetIcon(x, Icon) ;
  Use_ImageList->ReplaceIcon(x, Icon) ; 
  }
delete Icon ;
```

I fear the issue is in this part of the code !

**- Additional information -** after having done more testing

If I rewrite the code to something like:

```
TBitmap *Bitmap= new TBitmap () ;
for (int x = 0 ; x < OS_Specific_count ; x++)
  {
  OS_xx_ImageList->GetBitmap(x, Bitmap) ;
  Use_ImageList->Replace(x, Bitmap, NULL) ; 
  }
delete Bitmap;
```

I have similar problems, yet not exactly the same.  The transparency seems to get lost !

I have also noticed that:

```
Use_ImageList->AddImage(OS_xx_ImageList, x) ;
```

starting from an empty Use_ImageList seems to preserve all alpha channel data properly !
Maybe I should rewrite the code to always copy the lot this way ...

Comment: True color? Why not 32bpp, 8 pixels per channel.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - This is what IcoFX names it.  But it is a 32 bit icon with alpha channel and it comes straight out of the OS icon library/dll.

Comment: I use such icons quite happily in Delphi. Have done so since Delphi 6. Although back then we had to create the image list handle manually. What we cannot see is what you are doing. Perhaps there's a defect in your code. This is why we ask for a [mcve]. If you made an [mcve] then we could be 100% sure that we were looking at the same program as you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - You're right !!!  I have added a section at the bottom with new information.  I need to sign off but will follow up tomorrow.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Any idea why getting an icon or bitmap and replacing it in an ImageList 'corrupts' the alpha channel information ?

Comment: It would be obvious with an [mcve]

Comment: @DavidHeffernan -  I added a relevant comment to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144723/how-to-setup-a-ticon-instance-to-support-alpha-channel-icons-supportspartialtra
It comes down to the `ColorDepth` that needs to be set to `cd32Bit` before importing the alpha channel icons.  This is a very old project, the imagelists first made on a Win85 system  Nonetheless I mentioned that the ImageLists had their default properties, and `cd32Bit` isn't part of that.  I didn't know this was the key.  All should be fine now.  I can work with this. Thx

Comment: I'm not going to contribute any more of my time here. You won't make it easy for us to help because you refuse to add a [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry to have annoyed you @DavidHeffernan, I thought I had provided all information when I mentioned the ImageLists were created at design time with their default properties.  I wasn't aware one needs to list all properties of a component, even when nothing has been changed.

Comment: You have not annoyed me. I don't understand why you won't make a [mcve]. Anyway, it's obviously your choice. I believe that you'd get better help if you would show a [mcve]. You disagree. It's fine for us to disagree.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - But you keep saying I 'refuse' or 'disagree' ?  As far as I know I did provide all information to repeat the problem ? I honestly have provided all information there is to provide ?  This is a huge project.  I obviously can't copy all code.  I simply lifted the piece of code that causes the problem along with the information about the design time objects I could provide.  If they had been created at run time I would have copied that code as well. Bottom line I thought I provided a MCVE  So maybe this is all a big misunderstanding as I thought I had provided a MCVE Best, Peter

Comment: It's not complete. You've shown excerpts. Show a complete program that we can paste and compile.