# How to setup a TIcon instance to support alpha channel icons (SupportsPartialTransparency)

Tags: c++builder, delphi-2009, vcl

Using Borland C++ Builder 2009 I notice that when replacing images in a TImagelist, the alpha channel data gets corrupted somehow.

```
TIcon *Icon = new TIcon() ;
for (int x = 0 ; x < OS_Specific_count ; x++)
  {
  OS_xx_ImageList->GetIcon(x, Icon) ;
  Use_ImageList->ReplaceIcon(x, Icon) ; 
  }
delete Icon ;
```

The problem is also described (+screenhots) in another Q ( [TImageList - True color + alpha channel vs. 8-bit (256 colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121272/timagelist-true-color-alpha-channel-vs-8-bit-256-colors) ) but I'm now trying to narrow things down with more specific questions.

While browsing TIcon in the help file I noticed a read-only property: `SupportsPartialTransparency`.
It appears to be `false` in my case, and I wonder if this is not the key to solving this problem ?  `Icon->Transparent = true` does not set `SupportsPartialTransparency` to true !

I wonder what I can do to make sure the TIcon instance correctly 'gets' and 'replaces' the alpha channel information ?

The ImageLists are created at design time and have default properties (nothing changed) and contain 16x16 icons imported via the IDE.  The imported icons contain alpha channel information.

Comment: *Transparent* <> *Partial transparent*, any more than *dollar* ==  *half-dollar*. You keep asking questions regarding your image list without including the properties of that image list.

Comment: @KenWhite - default setting, 16x16 icons

Comment: And what is the ColorDepth? Are you setting it to cd32? You've been asked to provide a full MCVE in your other question, which would include the contents of the form file. I see you still haven't - please do so now. If you're not going to provide the details, it's pretty unlikely we're going to be able to help you, and at some point ignoring requests for more information is going to start annoying people. I can say with absolute certainty that alpha channel images work correctly; I have toolbars full of them on my apps, and I use alpha-channel icons in multiple sizes for my apps.

Comment: I'm sorry you're getting annoyed @KenWhite . The other Q mentions it but I added it here as well.  The ImageLists contain their default properties.  The properties they have when they are dropped onto a form.  For color depth that is: cdDeviceDependent
Are you saying I should set them to cd32 for copying as shown in the code example above to work correctly ?  I fail to see how Partial transparency of the icon instance is going to change ?  Or does it change when ImageList 'get's the icon ?  PS. alpha channel icons work for me too !  It's just that code-example above gets rid of channel data

Comment: @Peter: If you read the [`TImageList` documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Controls.TImageList), you will see that you are calling the version of `GetIcon()` that is subject to the `TImageList.DrawingStyle` property, which you say is still the default value, which is `dsNormal` by default. Try setting it to `dsTransparent` instead, or call the version of `GetIcon()` that has an `ADrawingStyle` parameter. And yes, set the `ColorDepth` to `cd32Bit` in order to handle images with alpha channels.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I set `ColorDepth` of both ImageLists to `cd32bit` at design time and imported the icons again.  Then I tested the code and this time it works.  This is an old project.  Time for a complete overhaul because I can't even find some of the icons in the ImageList to import again.  The `DrawingStyle` doesn't seem to influence things.  I don't need to set it at design time nor do I need to use the `GetIcon()` variant that takes `DrawingStyle` as input.  I tried but it doesn't seem to affect things either way.  Key seems to be that icons are imported before the `Colordepth` is set.

Answer (score -1):

I just use TPngImageList, it is compatible with TImageList. Plus the design-time editor is more flexible: You will need to convert .ico to .png. [image: editor].

It is free and widely available, for example here: https://github.com/TurboPack. No headache with transparency since :) BTW, keeping icons as PNGs is more suitable, you can use them on other development tools and platforms.